# Form not recognising invalid fields due to nested view and inherited model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

In my project I'm using Angular UI's ui-router for nested views. My layout (on a particular record page) looks like this:

[image]

On first load everything works great, the validation works, the form saves changes to the model etc. The problem arises when you make changes to the form leaving it in an invalid state, then browse to another sub nav link, and then go back again. At this point the previous loaded form had changed the model inherited from the parent view making it invalid, but the new form has loaded with that model believing all its fields to be pristine, and so the form is now in a valid state allowing the user to bypass clientside validation. I can't seem to make the form wake up and validate automatically again unless the user edits a field.

One way I can fix this is to load the model in the nested views controller, so when you click back to the form again from sub nav it loads a fresh model, but I don't feel that this is the right solution especially since on first load both the parent and sub view will both perform a GET for the model.

I'm a little stuck on this one, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've come up with for now is to copy the resource in the sub view controller:

```
$scope.parent.$watch('record', function(record) {
    if (!record) return;
    $scope.record = angular.copy(record);
}
```

This means each time the sub view is loaded it gets an updated copy from the parent so it doesn't persist the invalid changes.

It would be better to just nudge the validation to kick in properly but I can't see a way to do that currently.